# Trouble getting groups out of Regex

Tags: c#, regex

The following code only returns "Good job!" How can I get the actual URLs out of it? I followed the tutorial on the site given, and I'm still having a bit trouble wrapping my head around it. Also, I imagine that this isn't the best way to go about regex (mixing regex with html). Is there a simple way to capture text based on it's CSS class?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;



namespace Scraper
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string target = @"http://www.omegacoder.com/?p=58";
            HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(target);
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

            Regex URL  = new Regex("(?:href=)(?<link>.*?)");

            string line;
            using (Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream())
            using (StreamReader htmlStream = new StreamReader(responseStream))
                while ((line = htmlStream.ReadLine()) != null){

                    Match m = URL.Match(line);

            if (m.Success) {
                Console.WriteLine("Good job! " + URL.Match(line) + m.Groups[0].Value + m.Groups[1].Value + m.Groups["link"]);
                Console.ReadLine();
            } else {

            }

                }  
                /*    if (Regex.IsMatch(line, "XXXXX")) 
                            Console.WriteLine(line);
                } */
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what do you want to do with `css` class!your code is doing something else..do you want href's or text which has particular css class

Comment: Sorry. I want to scrape recipes off websites. I have found that one website puts the name/ingredients/method in different classes. That's how I'd like to store it in my own database.

Comment: can you be more specific about what you want..what are those `different classes`

Comment: Before I get into that I hope I can just scrape basic URLs off sites. As of right now this program returns only "Good job! href=" over and over

Comment: you better use `(?:href=)(?<link>\S*)` also it should be `m.Groups["link"].Value`

Comment: replacing ("(?:href=)(?<link>.*?)") with (?:href=)(?<link>\S*) works perfectly... although I don't get why. Another Regex tester (Expresso) show them both working just the same. Thanks a bunch

Comment: check out my ans..i have explained the regex..if that helps,you can accept the ans

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `(?:href=)(?<link>\S*)`

`\S` matches a character that is not space